# How to send a message using "net send" command within Windows "cmd"?

Tags: windows-xp, command-line

I have connected two PCs via LAN using a crossover cable, but I am unable to send the message using `net send` command in command prompt.

What do I have to do to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`msg username "message you want to send"`

Comment: still unable to send

Comment: Remove the quotes from around the username

Comment: Just see if you can see a message when you say `msg %username% Hello from %username%`

Answer (score 2):

As far as I remember, Net send should be used like the following but thru 2 cross-connected computers, I can't confirm that this will work... Never tried it.

> net send {name | * | /domain[:name] | /users} message

It should work exept if it has been blocked by policy or the service has been disabled.

**Source:** [Microsoft Website](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/net_send.mspx?mfr=true)

Comment: I just check in my MCP notes and it will not work! You must be logged in a domain do have this service send messages.

Comment: Yep check my answer above.

Comment: So +1 for you then!

Answer (score 1):

Reasons it wouldn't work:

- You aren't using a domain.  You have to be on a domain with persistent users across PCs.  The message gets sent to the USER not to the PC.
- Messenger service is disabled.  Some anti-spyware disables Windows Messenger service because it is used by spyware and adware to spoof system messages.

Comment: -1 because saying that a domain is required is just plain wrong.

Comment: I would be delighted to hear your answer then!  To use the net send, you must either use a domain user name OR specify a domain to send to.  Please indicate how either of these options excludes using a domain.